# Update query in android

Tags: android

I am trying to update the database on the basis of incoming parameter but it is not updated.
i am using the following code:

```
public static void markFavoriteStation(String station, boolean favorite){
    Log.d(AppConstants.TAG,"StationListDBIfc: +markFavoriteStation");
    String Query = null;
    mDb = bartDb.getWritableDatabase();

    Query = "update  stationlistTable  set  favorite  ='1'  where  namewithabbr = '+station'";

    mDb.rawQuery(Query, null);
    Log.d(AppConstants.TAG,"StationListDBIfc: -markFavoriteStation");
}
```

Comment: Did you try the query in the `sqlite3` app? Also, any reason why you don't use the `update` method instead?

Comment: I am having a similar problem. I tried a similar query in sqlite3 app and the database gets updated perfectly. However it does not get updated in through the application using the same query. Is there anything else what can be done to check what is going wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you might have a malformed String definition. You should end the String before concatenating the "station" variable to it, like so:

```
Query = "update stationlistTable set favorite ='1' where namewithabbr = '" + station + "'";
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any errors. I guess the SQL query has errors or the namewithabbr column doesn't contain what you expect. You should test it in the sqlite3 app.